# File is not being uploaded from front end

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, file-upload, varien-file-uploader

I am trying to upload a file from frontend. as bellow,

```
.phtml file

<label for="sb_link">Image</label>
<input type="file" id="bs_image" name="bs_image" required="true"/>
```

and in my controller I am doing

```
      if (isset($_FILES['bs_image']['name']) && $_FILES['bs_image']['name'] != '') {
                $path = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/test';
                if (!file_exists($path)) {
                    mkdir($path, 777, true);
                } try {

                    $fname = $_FILES['bs_image']['name'];
//                 $fname = $this->getRequest()->getParam('bs_image');
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('bs_image');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('png', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'docx'));
                    $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $uploader->save($path, $fname);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo 'Error Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
```

folder is present, and getting no `error/exception`, but file is not in folder. or there is an other way to do it. I was following [Owais Kiani's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873363/how-can-i-upload-image-from-front-end-in-magento)
post

Comment: @Qaisar Satti , what do you say about it

Comment: did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Yes,   <form id="product-form" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('abc_checkout/cart/addall'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` what is output of this?

Comment: replace `$path = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/test';`  with  `$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'test/'; `

Comment: output is "Array ( [bs_image] => Array ( [name] => jin.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phptxG3Wz [error] => 0 [size] => 8566 ) ) Array ( [bs_image] => Array ( [name] => jin.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phptxG3Wz [error] => 0 [size] => 8566 ) ) "

Comment: path problem update the path code then check and also clear ur cache. and check the folder permission is 777

Comment: now working, permission issue, thanks bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39550/discussion-between-abdul-ghaffar-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `$path = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/test';` with `$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'test/';`

Also clear ur cache. and check the folder `permission` is `777`